# java.util.ArrayList$SubList is not trusted

Tags: jackson

I am new to Spring batch. I want to use subList but I can not.
Could you help me to out of this error?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with java.util.ArrayList$SubList and name of java.util.ArrayList$SubList is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing.
```

Here's my code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i += take) { // 2까지
      if (leftOver > 0) {
        leftOver--;
        take = chunkSize + 1;
      } else {
        take = chunkSize;
      }
      ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
      Math.min(totalCount, i + take))));
      executionContext.put("result", new SmallerListCreator(ids, i, Math.min(totalCount, i + take)));
      partitionMap.put("partition_" + i, executionContext);
    }
```